# Sending email error using amazon ses ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, phpmailer

The following code used to send email using phpmailer function and amazon ses ec2, if i use different port(25, 465, 587) then getting different error.

```
 <?php
    require 'class.phpmailer.php';
    $to         = "********@gmail.com";
    $from       = "info@itlowers.com";   // verified mail id
    $subject    = "a test subject";
    $body       = "email body content goes here";

    $mail       = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(true);            // use SMTP

   $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;        // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                    // 1 = errors and messages
                                    // 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Host       = "email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com"; // Amazon SES server, note "tls://" protocol
    $mail->Port       = 465;                    // set the SMTP port
    $mail->Username   = "*************";  // SES SMTP  username
    $mail->Password   = "*****************";  // SES SMTP password

    $mail->SetFrom($from, 'First Last');
    $mail->AddReplyTo($from,'First Last');
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($body);
    $address = $to;
    $mail->AddAddress($address, $to);

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo "Message sent!";
    }
?>
```

I'm getting following errors

```
    SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
    SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
    SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server:
    SMTP -> FROM SERVER:
    SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server:
    SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server:
    SMTP -> NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connectedSMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

what i wrote wrong in my code?

Comment: the error message says your authentication (username, password) is incorrect.

Comment: The output shown is virtually useless.  I would suggest setting debug to 4.  Also, you need SMTPSecure = 'tls' and presumably the most correct port would be 465, which expects you to open a tls connection from the outset rather than using `STARTTLS`, although it's not clear from the module docs.  465 or 587 will be the right choice depending on how the module handles encryption.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Sending email with SMTP configured 
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com'; // "ssl://smtp.gmail.com" didn't worked
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
$mail->Username = "*****@gmail.com";  //enter your email username
$mail->Password = "***********";  //enter your Password

$mail->IsHTML(true); // if you are going to send HTML formatted emails
$mail->SingleTo = true; // if you want to send a same email to multiple users. multiple emails will be sent one-by-one.

$mail->From = "info@***.ca";
$mail->FromName = "From name";
$mail->AddAddress($email);
$mail->Subject = "Sales";
$mail->Body = "<html><head> </head><body style='width:700px;'>";

// your content here
.
.   
.
.
.
$mail->Body .="</body></html>"; 

if(!$mail->Send())
{
 echo "mail not send";
}
else 
{
 echo "mail sent";
}
```